# UICollectionViewCell not being reused correctly

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm building a chat functionality in this app and I experience something weird. I don't think the `UICollectionViewCells` are being reused correctly. When you send a new message or when you scroll fast a lot, you see the "bubble" is not being displayed correctly but if you scroll back and forth, they're back to normal, here are 2 screenshots of what it actually looks like:

[image]

[image]

```
class CurrentUserMessageLogCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let messageTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isSelectable = false
    textView.isEditable = false
    return textView
}()

let bubbleView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

let bubbleImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(bubbleView)
    addSubview(messageTextView)
    bubbleView.addSubview(bubbleImageView)
    bubbleImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bubbleImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    bubbleImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bubbleView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    applyTheme()
    updateView()
    messageTextView.text = ""
    bubbleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "")
}

var message: Message? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    if let text = message?.text {
        incomingOrOutgoingMessageWithCalculatedFrame(text: text)
        messageTextView.text = text
    }
}

func incomingOrOutgoingMessageWithCalculatedFrame(text: String) {
    let size = CGSize(width: 0.66 * contentView.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size,
                                                             options: options,
                                                             attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Regular, size: 13)!],
                                                             context: nil)

    if message?.fromId == Api.Users.CURRENT_USER?.uid {
        // outgoing message
        bubbleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "chat_bubble_outgoing")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 21, bottom: 17, right: 21)).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        bubbleImageView.tintColor = Theme.current.view_messageBubbleView_outgoing_backgroundColor
        messageTextView.textColor = Theme.current.textView_messageBubble_incoming_textColor

        bubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 50,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: estimatedFrame.width + 50,
                                 height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)

        messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 32,
                                     y: 0,
                                     width: estimatedFrame.width + 10,
                                     height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }
    else {
        // incoming message
        bubbleImageView.tintColor = Theme.current.view_messageBubbleView_incoming_backgroundColor
        messageTextView.textColor = Theme.current.textView_messageBubble_outgoing_textColor
        bubbleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "chat_bubble_incoming")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 21, bottom: 17, right: 21)).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        bubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 50, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
        messageTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: estimatedFrame.width + 20, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    } 
  }
 }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: messageCellId, for: indexPath) as! CurrentUserMessageLogCVCell
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.message = message
    return cell
}

func registerCells() {
    collectionView.register(CurrentUserMessageLogCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: messageCellId)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if let messageText = messages[indexPath.row].text {
        let estimatedFrame = estimateFrameForText(text: messageText)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height)
    }
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}

private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: 0.66 * view.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size,
                                                           options: options,
                                                           attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.OpenSans_Regular, size: 13)!],
                                                                    context: nil)
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
}
```

Any idea what's causing and how to fix this weird behaviour?

Comment: Check if setMessage is called on Main Thread, so that when `message` gets set and it calls `updateView()` it is on the main thread...Also why not set text in `incomingOrOutgoingMessageWithCalculatedFrame` already since you have the text there...

Comment: @Ladislav `updateView()` is indeed called on the main thread. As for the second question - it separates the fuctions just to make it a little cleaner. That's the only reason why really.

Comment: Check if maybe `updateView()` is called before the one that applys the theme, also I would suggest have 2 types of cells one that is used for incomming and one for outgoing messages, so that when you reuse you dont have to change colors, fonts, text colors, but just use the same always since you have two reuse identifiers

Comment: @Dani have tried reloading inner collectionView inside incomingOrOutgoingMessageWithCalculatedFrame method???

Comment: @Ladislav sorry for the late reply, took awhile to create 2 separate cells. That was no the issue as I've stated in the updated question above, BUT it helped me realize that it was something to do with the `applyTheme()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Ladislav , I've separated the cell into 2, one of the incoming messages and one for the outgoing. This didn't help in terms of solving the problem, but it helped me find out that the actual issue was in the `applyTheme()` function, more precisely, setting the `messageTextView.backgroundColor = .clear` which was messing up with the entire bubble image. All I had to do was to move that line in the constant declaration and this finally solved the issue.